# Isometric Mapping of two same Triangles

Tags: graphics, 3d, geometry, mapping, transformation

I mapped a 3D triangle to an arbitrary position in an arbitrary 2D plane using the lengths of 3 sides. So now the two triangles are exactly same but on different planes.

For a point inside the 2D triangle, I want to know its corresponding 3D point inside the 3D triangle, which I think is unique.

How do I achieve this? Is barycentric interpolation of the 2D-to-3D mapping precise? If yes, why?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Think in terms of vectors: if you have a triangle ABC on a plane, then for every point P on the same plane **AP** = m**AB** + n**AC** (I use bold to denote vectors). If you know the coordinates of A, B, C, P, it's easy to find m and n. Then if A3, B3, C3 your 3d-vertices, the corresponding point P3 would be such that **A3P3** = m**A3B3** + n**A3C3**. Knowing coordinates of A3, B3, C3, and using m and n you just found, you can find **P3**.

Notice that it's not the most efficient way if you need to move multiple points back to 3d space. However, then it turns into a question about linear algebra, and I'm not putting a lot of mathematics here. Hint: look where points (0, 0), (0, 1) and (1, 0) go -- it's enough to move any other point from the same plane to your 3d space.